# How to add drawable's next to textfield in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable

I am trying to figure out how to add a drawable to a text within a textfield (OutlinedTextField) but without any success. I have already created a drawable in the drawable folder. Do I need to create a seperate composable to insert it or can I directly add it inside the textfield ?

This is my textfield in the composable:

```
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = username.value,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                username.value = newText
            },
            label = { Text(text = "Username") },
            placeholder = { Text("") }, // placeholder / hint
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(180F)
        )
```

Comment: Use leadingIcon instead of place holder property

Comment: Are you talking about a leading icon or just an image inside the text?

Comment: Just a leading Icon, something that resembles this with the e-mail icon next to the text. https://gyazo.com/0efdcbf72fa066784c8f5991e013fc5a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use leadingIcon instead of placeHolder

```
           OutlinedTextField(
               value = username.value,
               onValueChange = { newText ->
                   username.value = newText
               },
               label = { Text(text = "Username") },
               leadingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Place, contentDescription = null)},
               modifier = Modifier
                   .fillMaxWidth(180F)
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use leading Icon and put Image instead of Icon

```
OutlinedTextField(
           value = username.value,
           onValueChange = { newText ->
               username.value = newText
           },
           label = { Text(text = "Username") },
           leadingIcon = { 
            Image(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(35.dp),
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.facebook),
                            contentDescription = "facebook icon",
                        )

    },
           modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth(180F)
       )
```